# Getting inappropriate value in byte datatype when assigning null value to it

Tags: c#, byte, automapper

I am getting problem in auto mapper **when binding byte value to null**.

This is my Variable:

```
public byte[] Intern { get; set; } //source 

 public byte[] Intern { get; set; } //Destination.
```

**Database Table**:

```
Intern Varbinary max
```

This is how i am mapping :

```
 .ForMember(s => s.Intern , opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Intern ==null ? null : src.Intern ))
```

Now in this Intern field i am getting value like this when condition is null:

```
Intern:byte[0];
```

And so because of this in database in Intern field it is storing like **ox** but i want to store **null**.

Can anybody tell me how to do this with automapper??

Comment: Your mapfrom currently always sets src.Intern to null, in all cases. and by `ox` do you mean the word `ox`?

Comment: Also, how are you saving to the database?

Comment: @Eris:yes i mean word ox